# How can i scale a service that has one credentials to connect to a external TCP service

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, architecture, autoscaling

I have a service with only one credentials to access another external service using a TCP connection.

Problem: I want to scale the service but i cant have two or more instances using the same credentials, and i dont have more credentials to use it.

So there's a way to scale this service using only one credentials?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Split the bit that communicates with that separate service into another service that stays a singleton.  Make your current service dependent on that other service.  Everything else around your current service can then scale at need.

If your constraint is your I/O with that external service, then scaling your internal service is not going to help.  It's an immovable constraint.  However if the scaling constraint are other parts of your internal service (database, processing, business logic, etc) then this architecture can help.

Comment: +1, you can use Nginx as forward proxy. There is a helm chart available, you can define only one pod running at a time.